# Testing the project by using Selinium ide add-on tool

Tags: facebook, gmail

I have recorded a Test script using Selenium IDE tool for the login functionality. while using that Tool identified that my log in link as element " id=aui_3_4_0_1_305". but  when I run the recorded script the tool shows me the error as "Element id=aui_3_4_0_1_305 not found".

Actually, I have recorded a Selenium (IDE) script for login functionality. In my recorded script, I have performed an operation "click" for "login" where the application always generate a new ID for Login link. So when I run the recorded script. application generates a new ID for login link and the tool shows me the error message as "Element id=aui_3_4_0_1_305 not found".

Please suggest me that how could I record my selenium script for these type of cases. Because every time when I run that recorded script it will show the same error message and discontinue the script.

In addition many of my friends says there must be a random error occurs due to the dynamic id's created newly for every time login functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your locator as an xpath using starts-with, I think the aui part would remain common.  Or use anything that remains common in the id value something like :
 `//input[starts-with(@id,'aui')]`.  Make sure you do not have other elements starting with aui, else the xpath would find multiple elements.

Comment: But many of them says that to change the id as unique by adding some functions before the id in program. but i don't know anything about program because i am just a black box Tester.

Comment: can you help me by explain it elaborately >

Comment: To deal with elements, you need to identify them uniquely.  In your question, you had specified that you are using id=aui_xxx as your locator to identify the element.  Since, this locator cahnges on every run of your case, a hardcoded one wouldn't work.  Xpath gives you a way to use kind of a regular expression, so that you can use what is constant.  So if you notice the changed ids of the element everytime, you should be able to find out a pattern which is constant, which can be used to identify the element.  So, instead of using id=xxx, try using the xpath that was suggested.